# Como criar um select no banco de dados que execute duas tabelas com uma unica chave primária?

Tags: c#, mysql, banco-de-dados, winforms, visual-studio

sou nova na programação e estou desenvolvendo um sistema de notas.
O caso é o seguinte: Existe um form que cadastra as notas, onde utiliza 2 tabelas do mysql, a tabela notas (onde são inseridos o código da nota, o código do funcionário, o código do cliente, data de emissao, valor, entre outros...), os dados vão para os textbox. 
Já a outra tabela é a notaprodutos (onde são inseridos os dados do produto, como notaID, produtoID, ValorProduto, Quantidade), que são listados por um listview

Existe outro form que criei para pesquisar as notas do cliente, então ao procurar o cliente, é listado todas as notas do cliente. Ao dar um duplo clique no listview, abre o form de cadastrar notas, porém com todos os dados da nota abertos.

**A questão está ai, como farei um select no banco de dados que execute as duas tabelas abrindo o notaID?**
Até o momento foi isso que fiz:

```
public List<EntidadeViewPesquisaNota> 
ListarEntidadeViewPesquisaNotaVisu(int codNota)
    {
        var ListarEntidadesNotaVisu = new List<EntidadeViewPesquisaNota>();
        using (MySqlConnection conexao = ConexaoBD.getInstancia().getConexao())
        {
            try
            {
                conexao.Open();
                MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand();
                comando = conexao.CreateCommand();


                comando.CommandText = @"SELECT NotaID, ClienteID, FuncionarioID, NumeroNota, DataEmissao, Status, DataPagamentoFinal, Desconto, ValorPago
                                 FROM nota";
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("NotaID", codNota);
                MySqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    //Objeto Usuario
                    var oNota = new EntidadeViewPesquisaNota();
                    oNota.NotaID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["NotaID"].ToString());
                    oNota.FuncionarioID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["FuncionarioID"].ToString());
                    oNota.ClienteID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ClienteID"].ToString());
                    oNota.NumeroNota = reader["NumeroNota"].ToString();
                    oNota.DataEmissao = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DataEmissao"].ToString());
                    oNota.Status = (Status)Convert.ToInt16(reader["Status"]);
                    oNota.DataPagamentoFinal = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DataEmissao"].ToString());
                    if ((reader["ValorPago"] != DBNull.Value))
                        oNota.ValorPago = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["ValorPago"].ToString());
                    if ((reader["Desconto"] != DBNull.Value))
                        oNota.Desconto = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Desconto"].ToString());
                    oNota.Produtos = new NotaProdutoBD().BuscarProdutosNota(oNota.NotaID);



                    ListarEntidadesNotaVisu.Add(oNota);
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                throw new System.Exception(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                conexao.Close();
            }
        }
        return ListarEntidadesNotaVisu;
    }`
```

E o chamei dessa forma:

```
        private void Bt_Abrir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var lista = new NotasNG().ListarEntidadeViewPesquisaNotaVisu(Convert.ToInt32(txt_CodigoNota));
        //Verifica se a lista está vazia
        if (lista.Count < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sem dados para serem exibidos!", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            return;
        }

        //Passa a lista para o formulário genérico de pesquisa de funcionário;

        var frmCadNota = new FrmCadNotas();
        frmCadNota.lista = lista;
        frmCadNota.ShowDialog();

        var iRetorno = frmCadNota.iRetorno;
        //iRetorno = 0
        if (iRetorno < 1)
            return;

        txt_CodigoNota.Text = iRetorno.ToString();

        Txt_CodigoNota_Validating(txt_CodigoNota, new CancelEventArgs());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Não conheço a linguagem C#, mas pelo o que entendi você tem uma tabela Nota, que tem como chave primária NotaID e recebe como chave estrangeira ClienteID, e você possui outra tabela NotaProduto, que possui como chave estrangeira NotaID e ProdutoID.

Nesse caso para fazer um select recebendo o NotaID para listar todas as NotaProduto associadas o fariamos:

```
SELECT Nota.NotaID, Nota.ClienteID, Nota.FuncionarioID, Nota.NumeroNota, Nota.Desconto, Nota.ValorPago, NotaProduto.ProdutoID,NotaProduto.ValorProduto,NotaProduto.Quantidade 
                             FROM Nota, NotaProduto WHERE Nota.NotaID = NotaProduto.NotaID AND Nota.NotaID = id_Nota_que_quer_buscar
```